# Simulating Game of Craps in JAVA

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was trying to learn by doing some excercises that I found online. So please excuse me if this is too naive.

This excercise was about writing a program for game of craps with the following rules:

> In the game of craps, a pass line bet proceeds as follows: Two six-sided dice are
>   rolled; the first roll of the dice in a craps round is called the “come out roll.”
>   A come out roll of 7 or 11 automatically wins, and a come out roll of 2, 3, or 12
>   automatically loses. If 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 is rolled on the come out roll, that number
>   becomes “the point.” The player keeps rolling the dice until either 7 or the point is
>   rolled. If the point is rolled first, then the player wins the bet. If a 7 is rolled first,
>   then the player loses.
>   Write a program that simulates a game of craps using these rules without human
>   input. Instead of asking for a wager, the program should calculate whether the
>   player would win or lose. The program should simulate rolling the two dice and
>   calculate the sum. Add a loop so that the program plays 10,000 games. Add
>   c ounters that count how many times the player wins, and how many times the
>   player loses. At the end of the 10,000 games, compute the probability of winning
>   [i.e., Wins / (Wins + Losses)] and output this value. Over the long run, who
>   is going to win the most games, you or the house?

Here is the code that I have written :

```
// GAME OF CRAPS
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  int dice1 = 0;
  int dice2 = 0;
  int scorenew = 0;
  int point = 0;
  int wins = 0;
  int loss = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    System.out.println ("roll the dices");
    int score = roll (dice1, dice2);
    System.out.println ("\n score " + score);

    if (score == 11 || score == 7)
    {
      System.out.println ("\n Score = " + score);
      System.out.println ("you win");
      wins = wins + 1;
    }
    if (score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12)
    {
      System.out.println ("\n Score = " + score);
      System.out.println ("you lose");
      loss = loss + 1;
    }
    else if (score == 4 || score == 5 || score == 6 || score == 8 || score == 9 || score == 10)
    {
      point = point + score;
      System.out.println ("\n Point = " + point);

      do
      {
        scorenew = roll (dice1, dice2);
        System.out.println ("\n Score new = " + scorenew);
        if (scorenew == point)
        {
          System.out.println ("\n you win");
          wins = wins + 1;
          point = 0;
          break;
        }
        if (scorenew == 7)
        {
          System.out.println ("\n you lose");
          point = 0;
          loss = loss + 1;
          break;
        }
      } while (scorenew != point || scorenew != 7);

    }
  }

  System.out.println ("\n number of wins = " + wins
    + " and number of loss = " + loss +
    " and the probability for winning a game = " + (double) wins / (wins + loss));
}

public static int roll (int d1, int d2)
{
  Random randomGenerator = new Random ();
  int dice1 = randomGenerator.nextInt (6) + 1;
  int dice2 = randomGenerator.nextInt (6) + 1;

  System.out.println ("\n dice1 = " + dice1 + " dice2 = " + dice2);

  int score = dice1 + dice2;
  return score;
}
```

Everytime I run the code the do-while condition gets executed first, so please can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
} while(scorenew!=point || scorenew != 7);
```

This condition is *always* true, so you have an infinite loop. Also, why do you pass `d1` and `d2` into the `roll()` function? They are completely unused and unneeded.

Comment: Theres no infinite loop here.

Comment: Then tell me--for what values of `scorenew` and `point` is this expression false?

Comment: `scorenew == 7` and `point != 7`. The conditionals with the breaks will never let those values be evaluated, but they also break, so there is no infinite loop. It could be while(true).

Comment: No, the expression is still true with those values, because the first half will be true. That's my point--it's a while (true). The fact that there's a condition there strongly implies that he expects it to be a real and meaningful condition. He clearly misunderstands the booleans here. It's a sign that something is fundamentally wrong, even if breaks elsewhere in the code might mitigate the error.

Comment: "He clearly misunderstands the booleans here." As do i apparently. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do while is doing exactly what it you should expect it to do. Executes the body first then evaluates the conditional to see if it should run again. You don't actually need a do while though, you want to run until one of the conditions breaks you out of the while loop.

```
else {
  point = score;
  System.out.println ("\n Point = " + point);

  while (true) {
    scorenew = roll (dice1, dice2);
    System.out.println ("\n Score new = " + scorenew);
    if (scorenew == point) {
      System.out.println ("\n you win");
      wins = wins + 1;
      break;
    }
    if (scorenew == 7) {
      System.out.println ("\n you lose");
      loss = loss + 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Like @Lee Daniel Crocker said you don't need to pass in dice1 and dice2 to the roll function.

```
public static int roll() {
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int dice1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
  int dice2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
  System.out.println("\n dice1 = " + dice1 + " dice2 = " + dice2);
  return dice1 + dice2;
}
```

Another thing that might help is not declaring all the variables at the top of your method. You don't need scorenew or point outside of the third condition, in fact you don't need scorenew at all since you have point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  int wins = 0;
  int loss = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    System.out.println("roll the dices");
    int score = roll();
    System.out.println("\n score " + score);

    if (score == 7 || score == 11) {
      System.out.println("\n Score = " + score);
      System.out.println("you win");
      wins = wins + 1;
    } else if (score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12) {
      System.out.println("\n Score = " + score);
      System.out.println("you lose");
      loss = loss + 1;
    } else {
      int point = score;
      System.out.println("\n Point = " + point);
      while (true) {
        score = roll();
        System.out.println("\n Score new = " + score);
        if (score == point) {
          System.out.println("\n you win");
          wins = wins + 1;
          break;
        }
        if (score == 7) {
          System.out.println("\n you lose");
          loss = loss + 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  System.out.println("\n number of wins = " + wins
      + " and number of loss = " + loss +
      " and the probability for winning a game = " + (double) wins / (wins + loss));
}

public static int roll() {
  ...
}
```